# How to create a CSS border surrounding an input box?

Tags: html, css, forms, user-interface, border

I cannot seem to Google my way out of this one. I am trying to re-create the input box shown below. I would like to create a subtle transparent border outside the input box (will be a bit less transparent, kind of hard to see in mock-up.)

It seems to be making the border inside of the text box, not outside it. Also it is making a sharp highlight on the bottom of the border (possibly the bottom of the input box itself.)

### Mock-up Images

[image: example1]
[image: example2]

### My CSS for the input box

```
#merchantForm>form>input.inputValue {
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 30px; width: 350px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 19px; color: #333;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Any ideas? I'm kind of new to CSS, so any suggestions to improve my CSS is welcomed as well.

Comment: I suggest adding `box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;` at the end of the box-shadow line. For the use of any other browsers that implement such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The background of an element extends underneath the border by default. To change this behaviour use the following:

```
-webkit-background-clip: content-box;
   -moz-background-clip: content-box;
        background-clip: content-box;
```

Another, simpler option is to use the spread property of CSS box-shadows:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
```

Comment: Perfect :D Thanks!! One question, what is the -pre-box-shadow as apposed to box-shadow? I googled it and came up with nothing.

Comment: I would love to know! I have no idea how I typed pre instead of moz, my mind must have been elsewhere!

Answer (score 0):

you could just add an input background-image: to your field in your css image sprite and call it a day and have consistency in all browsers.

Comment: I think like 15% of users are still using ie8 or less then so border radius won't work in those browsers.  But if it for mobile then never mind I guess. don't get me wrong I'm all about css3. but you if this is for a client and they want it in ie8- you end of doing an image any way.

Comment: I thought about that, but it is acceptable for ie8 and below to not see the border, or shadows. The target audience is very techie, and the site is aiming at getting slammed with traffic, so extra http requests are not desired. We may end up doing a polyfill for those few with IE7,8. Great point though!

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick. =) (Rough sample: http://d.pr/nDaN)

```
input.custom-input {
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    border: none;
    border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 5px #CCC;
}
```

Comment: How is this not what the OP is after?  He wanted to create the styling that resembled the sample image.  I wrote the CSS that would do that.

Comment: Your code worked, with the exception of the border being transparent. it ended up being gray instead of transparent black. I found a work around however. If I sample the PSD document, I can get a solid color that's close... as long as the background didn't change.